# Can I use new certificate and provisioning profile to add version of my app on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, iphone

My provision profiles and developer distribution certificates has been  expired. Can I use new certs and provision profile for my app to update version of my running app

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this. but only bundle identifier of your project make same.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to edit section of profile and create new one. You can also create new certificate and use it. Don't worry. Revoke & create new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but Bundle identifier of your project should not be different.enjoy....:)